# How to truncate a delimited string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string of delimited numerical values just like this:

```
5|2288|502|4208|55|23217|235|10|3845|19053|1885|61|324|9004| ...etc.
```

Depending on the circumstance, the string may have only 1 value, 15 values,  all the way up to 100s of values, all pipe delimited.

I need to count off (and keep/echo) the first 10 values and truncate everything else after that.

I've been looking at all the PHP string functions, but have been unsuccessful in finding a method to handle this directly.

Comment: You can use explode function and use foreach loop to print values upto 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode()` to separate the elements into an array, then you can slice off the first 10, and `implode()` them to create the new string.

```
$arr = "5|2288|502|4208|55|23217|235|10|3845|19053|1885|61|324|9004";
$a = explode ('|',$arr);
$b = array_slice($a,0,10);
$c = implode('|', $b);
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Clearly I was looking in the wrong place for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Explode function

```
$arr = explode("|",$str);
```

It will break complete string into an array.
EG:  arr[0] = 5, arr[1] = 2288 .....

Answer (score 0):

I would use explode to separate the string into an array then echo the first ten results like this

```
$string = "5|2288|502|4208|55|23217|235|10|3845|19053|1885|61|324|9004";

$arr = explode("|", $string);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$str = '5|2288|502|4208|55|23217|235|10|3845|19053|1885|61|324';


$arrayString = explode('|', $str);
$cnt = 0;
$finalVar = '';
foreach ($arrayString as $data) {
    if ($cnt > 10) {
        break;
    }

    $finalVar .= $data . '|';
    $cnt++;
}
$finalVar = rtrim($finalVar, '|');
echo $finalVar;
```